# How do you know if an application running on a host is making the full use of its processing power?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, load-testing, host

How do you judge/understand how well its doing based on real time traffic and extrapolate how to scale the host capacity?

What I could come up was to base the understand of the load around TPS (Transactions per second), but whenever the load would get out of hand, the extrapolation would not make sense.

What other robust methodology is there to know how well your application is utilizing the host's CPU or IO.

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally you should have monitoring of baseline OS health metrics in place, it can be done either using built-in tools of the underlying operating system or an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) or an agent which comes with the load testing tool like [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
2. When you start load test make sure to increase the load **gradually**, this way you will be able to correlate increasing number of users with increasing number of transactions and resources utilization
3. At some point you will notice that you're increasing the load but the throughput (transactions per second) number remains the same or even goes down. This is called [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html)
4. Once you reach the saturation point you will need to identify the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing), the most common reasons are in:

   - Lack of resources, i.e. application slows down due to not enough memory
   - Incorrect configuration of the middleware, i.e. application or database server. The majority of such software default configuration is fine for development and/or debugging the applications but they need to be tuned for high loads, refer documentation for them
   - Your application code issues, i.e. inefficient algorithms which don't fully utilize CPU cores or generating slow DB queries. Use [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) to perform deep analysis of what exactly your application is doing under the load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look into [Windows Performance Monitor](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10)

Whenever you start generating load on an application (using any tool), Performance monitor (also known as perfmon) will provide you all the details regarding your Host

You can set your own performance counters to monitor specific process.